# Don't concat array as string when passed in parameter javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am running into a strange issue. I have an array called `args` which looks like this (printed in console log). Note that `Array(1)` is another array inside this array.

```
["1", Array(1), "", "abc", "", "", "def", "2"]
```

When I pass this array as a parameter to a function like this `onclick="myFunction(' + args + ')"` , I get the error:

> **SyntaxError: expected expression, got ',' myFunction(1,element1,,abc,,,def,2)**

It doesn't work when I change empty string to null either. `["1", Array(1), null, "abc", null, null, "def", "2"]`. Same error. How do I get around this?

Comment: Nice question. Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: What will be the expected argument for the above array?

Comment: Don't use inline `onclick` . Add an event listener instead and no such problem exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your array has quotes in it, which are getting processed inside the `onclick` attribute.  You can replace the quotes with their XML representation (`&quot;`) to avoid that problem, like this:

```html
<button onclick="console.log([&quot;1&quot;, Array(1), &quot;&quot;, &quot;abc&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, &quot;def&quot;, &quot;2&quot;]);">Click Me</button>
```

Or, you could use one type of quotes (single or double) for the outer limit of the argument, and one set inside the argument, like this:

```js
function myFunction(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}
```

```html
<button onclick='myFunction(["1", Array(1), "", "abc", "", "", "def", "2"])'>Click Me</button>
```

Either of those methods will print out your arguments correctly.

Comment: or use single quotes -- JS allows either double- or single-quotes to indicate string literals, in order to make it easy to embed them in other strings without escaping. (oops, I wrote this while you were updating your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
var array = ["1", [ "blah" ], "abc", "", "", "def", "2"];

//put the onclick on the element, not as an attribute of the html
div.onclick = function(){
  console.log(array);
};

div.innerHTML = "Click Me";

document.body.appendChild(div);
```